# sort map as per lati and long

Tags: java, android, sorting, latitude-longitude

i have `Map<String, Page>` data in this i have `data.getlat` and `data.getlog`. And in listview I am showing this data. I want this data should load as per nearest lat long 1st. Any idea how I can sort this

```
String s = "some data "
Listpojo ps = CoreGsonUtils.fromJson(s, Listpojo.class);
```

In ps I have all values. In ps I have data model which have lat, so i am accessing it like:

```
ps.data.getlat();
```

pl let know how to sort

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the nearest location,you should find the distance between the current location and the available locations.

Suppose You're in GERMANY. and Available locations are INDIA and US.
Now you should've the coordinates of these three locations.

You could able to calculate the distance from 2lon and 2lat by below class.

```
public class GeoHelper {

    public static String getDistance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {

        double theta = lon1 - lon2;
        double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = rad2deg(dist);
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = dist * 1.609344;
        return (String.valueOf(dist));
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts decimal degrees to radians             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private static double deg2rad(double deg) {
        return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
    }

    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    /*::  This function converts radians to decimal degrees             :*/
    /*:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
    private static double rad2deg(double rad) {
        return (rad * 180 / Math.PI);
    }
}
```

Suppose the coordinates of Germany is 5.0 lat, 3.5 lon and the cords of INDIA is 3.5Lat , 6.5 Lon.

So the distance can be find like this

```
String distance = GeoHelper.getDistance(5.0,3.5,3.5,6.5);
```

After looping through each available location with the current location like this, you could get the distance from the current location to each available location. So the nearest location will be the lowest distance.

Comment: how i can do this in hap which access bye list and i have n number of lat

Comment: map typo .. so i have list say 100 no then how i can sort it

Comment: so i have to make one temp list

Comment: Fine. this can be done in many ways. . i used to store the location data in the database and query the data by `DISTANCE`. this will sort the data by the distance. If you just want to find the nearest location while calculating distances, you could compare prev calculated  distance with the current calculated distance from the loop it self. and store the lowest distance some where outside the loop.